# Insert Image to firebase using xamarin form

Tags: image, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

My problem is how to insert image in firebase.

I tried some reasearch but it says, use firebase storage, is it possible to have another way like to insert in firebase realtime ? not in storage.

For now this is my codes;
registration page.xml
`

```
 <StackLayout
                                Padding="10">
                                <Image 
                                    x:Name="Imgresult" 
                                    HeightRequest="100" />
                                <Button 
                                    Text="Upload Valid ID" 
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    HeightRequest="45"
                                    TextColor="White" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                    BackgroundColor="#0e3663" 
                                    Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"
                                    Margin="0,25,0,0"/>

                            </StackLayout>
```

`

codebehind.cs
`

```
 async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Upload a clear copy of your valid ID"
            });

            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            
        }
```

`
any link that will posted about my post will be appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: every post I've seen says to use Firebase Storage

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but I left an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only store JSON data types. So to store an image in the database, you'll have to store it as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: aah okay sir,so after storing it to firebase storage sir, how I can put that string to my table property in firebase real time db?

Comment: There's nothing magical here: just like you have to encode the image into a string when you store it, you'll have to decode it when you read it. If you've never done this before, I recommend searching for [how to base64 encode/decode data on Xamarin/in C#.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+base64+encode%2Fdecode+data+on+Xamarin%2Fin+C%23)

Comment: thank you sir, I will update here if what's the result, Im currently doing it rn, base on your link posted.

Comment: hello sir,Just what I replied to sir @Liqun Shen-MSFT, I successfully added my image to storage and it reflect also in my realtime db however in my table propert "CusValiIdImage"( stands for CUSTOMER VALID ID IMAGE), I got this value  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***-system-*****.******.com/o/*************-***********************8.jpeg?alt=media&token=*******************************

I just make it an asterisk hehe But I think its the link of my storage( maybe?). Pls help sir :(

Answer (score 0):

My workflow is:

1. Pick a photo using **MediaPicker**
2. Convert the photo to *base64 encoded string* // you could refer to my code.
3. Upload the *base64 encoded string* to **Firebase RealTime Database**
4. The client sync the *base64 encoded string* from **Firebase RealTime Database** to app
5. The client transform the *base64 encoded string* to origin image

I use **Firebase Realtime Database** instead of **Firebase Storage** here.
And the whole workflow you could refer to the tutorial i put at the end of the answer.

=========== First post=========

As @Frank van Puffelen said, you have to convert the image stream to base64 encoded string when using Firebase Realtime db, you could try the following code:

```
byte[] bytes;
string base64str;
async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
    var mstream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(mstream);         
    bytes = mstream.ToArray();
    base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes,Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
}
```

To insert data into Firebase Realtime database, you could refer to this video: [Getting Started with Firebase Realtime Database and Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tWcv2_HK9E) and its code sample  [XFFirebaseRealtimeDBSample](https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFirebaseRealtimeDBSample).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you sir, I will update you if what is the result.

Comment: hello sir, I tried some research and now I follow some codes from internet in how to get  the file or image then display to my UI. and your code means that the Image I selected will be converted into string? but it will store to realtime? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-storage-crud-operations2/ that link I followed sir

Comment: I have updated my answer and does my workflow make sense for your case? If it does, could you please tell me which step you have achieved?

Comment: hey sir, I achieve the step 1 but I declare PickPhotoAsycnc.
I already insert the image to my firebase realtime but its the link of my firebase storage, you can refer to my reply to sir @Frank van Puffelen, and idk sir if its correct. Could you tell me if its wrong or not? Anyway, This is my code how I make it. https://codeshare.io/8pw0ej

Comment: from your code i found you use firebaseStorage to upload your photo to **firebase storage** selected by the photopicker. And you get the download link. However, i didn't find any code related to **firebase realtime database**.

Comment: Firebase storage and firebase realtime database are two different services provided by google firebase. I think you should determine which one you are going  to use.

Comment: oooh,I see my bad, so I need to change my code sir ?

Comment: I think you should determine which one you are going to use.--- I will use  the realtime sir but then again some solution in the internet is, when using storing image to db, they use storage.I try also searching if how to insert it to realtime however I cant find any tutorial( like a whole tutorial).

Comment: Have you tried this? [Getting Started with Firebase Realtime Database and Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tWcv2_HK9E) and [its code](https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFirebaseRealtimeDBSample).

Comment: sir, Actualy I already insert some data to my realtime, but its firstname,lastname, radiobutton/datepicker/picker value,Im just having hard time inserting image :(

Comment: Im searching now sir the suggestion(links and codes posted) you and sir frank van gave to me, in how to convert the image to my realtime database.

Comment: so my code sir is wrong? like the URL is save in my realtime db, but that URL is from firebase storage which contains the image.

Comment: You said you have inserted some values in Realtime Database?  Then to insert image, just convert image stream to base64 encoded string and then insert it in Realtime Database

Comment: so base on the link I commented in our thread sir, so I wont use that upload function? because it contains firebase storage? right?

Comment: Then to insert image, just convert image stream...
which code I will insert your code sir? in my create button or in my ImageButton_Clicked?

Comment: After you select the photo using media picker. Then convert it to string

Comment: is it okay sir If I will use the sample code in the link( below)? is it same with mediapicker and photoasync?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-storage-crud-operations2/

Comment: You could use its code a reference. Also you could refer to this article [Firebase Realtime Database with a Xamarin Forms Mobile App](https://medium.com/@jonwoods590/firebase-realtime-database-with-a-xamarin-forms-mobile-app-56c85be422de)

Comment: Hello sir, I tried your code. Can you see it here? https://codeshare.io/8pw0ej

Comment: First you pick the photo. Then you should convert it to string. And then you should upload it to Realtime Database

Comment: so I dont need that Upload function sir, right? cause Im using firebase storage?

Comment: That depends on what function you want to realize.